# Which one to choose? 3X9 or 3X8 groupset?

Tags: shimano, hybrid-bike

I am looking out buy a hybrid from either of these brands viz. TreK, Giant, Merida.

Now, there are 3X9 and 3X8 groupsets?

Will a 3X9 be more speedier?

Or should I go for a 2X10 groupset? (Ideally, Scott Metrix 20 which the sales guy suggested.)

Which among these three would be ideal?

Thanks!

NK

Comment: This is largely a matter of opinion. Since you've not stated what kind of riding you do, we can't give any informed advice.

Comment: Shopping advice is off-topic on this site, which is why you are attracting close votes. You can modify your question to ask what are the relative pros and cons of 2x8, 2x9, 2x10 drivetrains an what you should consider when buying, to bring it back on topic.

Comment: The close votes are a bit harsh (in my opinion), whilst the wording might not be great, the question is clearly seeking advice on the merits of different gear configurations.

Comment: http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=QHZ48AE3TOI&t=0m13s

Comment: Triples are outdated and have no longer a reason for existence. You'll by old stuff. Nowadays 2x11 covers the the same range with less complicated mechanics.Be aware that you may be sold something from days long gone, unless you can really haggle for a very low price.

Answer (score 1):

There are a host of factors that will affect how fast the bike is, how well it fits you, total weight, tire size and pressure etc.

Just considering the number of gears though, in general, more gears are better. More sprockets in the rear means smaller steps between gear ratios - or a lower lowest gear ratio which can be good if you live in a hilly area.

There is a definite advantage to a 2x10 drivetrain as you will not have to shift the front as often, but it might not have the total gear ratio range as a 3x9 system - check what the highest and lowest available gear ratios are.

I believe that 3x8 speed is only available at the lowest level of Shimano and SRAMs groupset offerings. Groupsets with more gears are generally better quality, lighter an more durable, and are fitted to similarly better quality bikes. A bike with a 2x10 groupset will very likely be lighter and have better frame, wheels and brakes than a 3x9 bike. In the end you have to make a choice of how much you want to spend and what is good enough for you.

Answer (score 0):

Ideal is such a strong word, and I am afraid neither of them is ideal.

For moderate recreational or commute usage, they will provide very similar performance. They would differ more in price (both at start but also in maintenance cost, like cost of chain replacement), smoothness of operation, and possibly durability (so components would need to be replaced more often).

With 3x8 being oldest, I would expect it to be the cheapest, robust, and  possibly a bit less refined in shifting, and cheap to maintain.

As for 2x10 being newest, I would expect it to be the most expensive, probably most refined, but somewhat less durable and certainly more expensive to maintain.

Keep in mind these are just rough generalization, top of the line 3x8 component could be more refined or more durable than bottom of the line 2x10 component.

For me personally 3x9 is currently sweet spot, other people would have different preferences.